# ShadowDOM vs Document Fragments -- How do they differ?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, documentfragment, angular2viewencapsulation

Looking into articles on ShadowDOM it seems like it's an enhancement to DocumentFragments. What is the real benefit of ShadowDOM? CSS specificity? Can't I do roughly the same things with Fragments?

I'm looking for a list of capabilities for each. For example, both seem to allow you to assemble a dom tree in memory and off the main render path. However, ShadowDOM seems to have the added benefit of scoped CSS.

What are cases where you would use ShadowDOM vs where you would just want to use DocumentFragments?

**UPDATE**

After looking into this more myself, I see the two technologies are completely orthogonal.

Note: *Since the question has been closed, I cannot answer it myself. I originally put details of my findings into a comment below, but figured more people will check the text up here.*

**Document Fragments** are a Javascript/DOM construction tool, used for creating a non-heirarchical collections of nodes (each of which could be the parent of other nodes) off the DOM. They are essentially a wrapper around the node-collection, which gets abandoned once the fragment is appended to the DOM. DocumentFragments allow you to collect a number of nodes at the same level, and append them to another DOM node as siblings.

**Shadow Dom** is all about isolation of side-effects within a larger rendered DOM. ShadowDom allows you to create sandboxed reusable components with encapsulated styles. When a ShadowDom-based component is added to a larger web application, its CSS styles will not leak out into the rest of the application, nor will the application's own styles affect the rendering of the component.

Note that CSS combinators such as `/deep/` and `::shadow` exist for styling (and selecting) shadowDom components from the parent dom, but these are being deprecated in the near future. Because of this, it is recommended reusable Components utilizing ShadowDOM rely on CSS Variables for styling, if they intend to be customized by the application that consumes them.

Comment: Not sure how this is "primarily opinion based". I haven't asked for any opinions, but an objective comparison and contrasting of capabilities and purposes.

Comment: The edit should be moved to an answer. So the question should be reopened.

Comment: As a noob studying web components I had the same question and learned alot here. These types of questions shouldn't be closed but once answered should be locked to prevent answer spam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've read and the way I use it, is **ShadowDom** has to do with **encapsulation** like if you put a `<style>` tag inside the **ShadowDom** the css will only be applied to the **ShadowDom** and document fragments has to do with browser reflow

Comment: I'd also add that, the two have completely different focuses. Document Fragments are a dom construction tool, used for creating a non-heirarchical collection of dom nodes (which themselves could have a hierarchy) off the dom. They are essentially a wrapper around the node-collection, which gets abandoned once the fragment is appended to the dom. This allows you to collect a number of nodes at the same level, and drop them into the dom as siblings. Shadow Dom is all about isolation of side-effects within rendered doms.